# How do I switch between keyboards if accessibility button is displayed in bottom-right corner?

Tags: samsung, keyboard, accessibility

In the rightmost area of the navigation bar, button for fast switching between keyboard apps (e. g. SwiftKey and Hacker Keyboard) is visible when a keyboard is open. But if accessibility button is displayed in that area, original keyboard switching button is always suppressed.

What is the fastest way to switch between keyboard-providing apps in such a case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same question.  So far I have found two answers but neither are as elegant as having the dedicated keyboard switch button. I'm using a Samsung S10e on Android 12.

1. you can install the Keyboard Switcher app by Kunzisoft.  It offers a few different keyboard switching options.  A floating button is one option, but alternatively you can choose to include a button in the notifications area.  It works well and is accessible from any app at anytime.  Just display notifications by pulling down from the top of the screen and you will see the keyboard switcher. Click it to change keyboards.
2. The other option (which may only be available in Android 12), is you can change the accessibility icon on the navigation bar to a floating button instead of the little man and your keyboard button will return to the lower right corner. To convert the little man to a floating button, go to 'Settings'>'Accessibility'>'Advanced Settings'>'Accessibility button'. Choose floating over apps instead of navigation bar.

Both solutions work but neither are as tidy as I would like. I'll update my post if I find something else.

Comment: I like option number one. There is also another app called *Keyboard Switcher* (indentical with app mentioned by you) in the Play Store, both work a bit differently. Anyway, switching keyboards via notification is definitely a way – thank you for pointing me in that direction.